# LASSO shrinking variables RLM finds important

Tags: regression, lasso, rlm

Comparing results from LASSO and robust regression I find that in some cases variables with high magnitude coefficients in robust regresison are shrunk to 0 in LASSO.

Any intuition here? Coefficients below.

| lasso_s0 | rlm_coef | variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 59.3544 | X9132 |
| -0.7579 | 27.4932 | X7729 |
| 10.494 | 20.4771 | X7353 |
| 0 | 18.0548 | X8361 |

For reference my R calls are attached

```
rr <- MASS::rlm(x=x, y = y, maxit=200)


cv_model <- cv.glmnet(x=x %>% as.matrix, y=y, alpha = 1)
best_model <- glmnet(x %>% as.matrix, y, alpha = 1, lambda = cv_model$lambda.min)
```

Comment: Different methods produce different results, especially when they target different areas of concern (outliers vs. overfitting almost colinear variables).  For example it looks as if your LASSO coefficients have substantial shrinkage.

Comment: What are these variables? (Solving a statistics problem without context is like boxing while blindfold. You might knock your opponent out but you might bash your hand on the ringpost).  

Generally, RLM and LASSO are designed to do different things. 

RLM isn't for variable selection. It adjusts for violations of the assumptions of OLS regression. M estimation (which is what RLM uses by default) is good when the errors are skewed.  (continued in next comment)

Comment: LASSO is not for violations of the OLS model and it IS a variable selection method. It's a penalized method, and adjusts some coefs to 0 (as you saw). It's better than forward, backward and so on, but still has the problems of being an automatic method.